# Plot multiple distributions by year using ggplot Boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

[image]

I'm trying to evaluate the above data in a boxplot similar to this: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/89-box-and-scatter-plot-with-ggplot2.html

[image: Text]

I want the x axis to reflect my "Year" variable and each boxplot to evaluate the 8 methods as a distribution. Eventually I'd like to pinpoint the "Selected" variable in relation to that distribution but currently I just want this thing to render!

I figure out how to code my y variable and I get various errors no matter what I try.  I think the PY needs to be as.factor but I've tried some code that way and I just get other errors.

anyway here is my code (Send Help):

```
# Libraries

library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl) # For reading in Excel files
library(lubridate) # For handling dates
library(dplyr) # for mutate and pipe functions

# Path to current and prior data folders
DataPath_Current <- "C:/R Projects/Box Plot Test"

Ult_sum <- read_excel(path = paste0(DataPath_Current, "/estimate.XLSX"), 
                                           sheet = "Sheet1",
                                           range = "A2:J12",
                                           guess_max = 100)

# just want to see what my table looks like
Ult_sum
# create a dataset - the below is code I commented out

# data <- data.frame(
# name=c(Ult_sum[,1]),
#     value=c(Ult_sum[1:11,2:8])
#)

value <- Ult_sum[2,]

  # Plot
Ult_sum %>%
  ggplot( aes(x= Year, y= value, fill=Year)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
  geom_jitter(color="black", size=0.4, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=11)
  ) +
  ggtitle("A boxplot with jitter") +
  xlab("")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not see how your code matches the screenshot of your dataset. However, just a general hint: ggplot likes data in long format. I suggest you reshape your data using `tidyr::reshape_long` oder `data.table::melt`. This way you get 3 columns: year, method, value, of which the first two should be a factor. The resulting dataset can then be neatly used in `aes()` as `aes(x=year, y=value, fill=method)`.

Edit: Added an example. Does this do what you want?

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr) 
library(ggplot2)
DT <- data.table(year = factor(rep(2010:2014, 10)),
                 method1 = rnorm(50),
                 method2 = rnorm(50),
                 method3 = rnorm(50))

DT_long <- DT %>% melt(id.vars = "year")

ggplot(DT_long, aes(x = year, y = value, fill = variable)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  However, there should only be 1 boxplot per year.  and the boxplot evaluates the distribution of the different methods.  For instance, year 4/1/10 (the first row) has a min value of 254,185 (method 3), max value of 466,968 (method 5), and a median of 304,425.

Comment: Ok, so in the above code just remove `fill = variable`. Then the boxplots will be calculated using all values from all methods by year. The backdrop is that you can't tell anymore from what method min, max, median stem. If this is not what you want, I am afraid I do not entirely understand your problem.